# docker-compose as a production environment without internet

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm a beginner with docker and I created a docker-compose file that can provide our production environment and I want to use it for our client servers for production environment also I want to use it locally and without internet.
Now, I have binaries of docker and docker compose and saved images that I want to load to a server without internet. this is my init bash script on Linux :

```
#!/bin/sh -e

#docker
tar xzvf docker-18.09.0.tgz
sudo cp docker/* /usr/bin/
sudo dockerd &

#docker-compose
cp docker-compose-Linux-x86_64 /ussr/local/bin/docker-compose
chmod +x /ussr/local/bin/docker-compose

#load images
docker load --input images.tar
```

my structure :

- code/*
- nginx/

  - site.conf
  - logs/
- phpfpm/
- postgres/

  - data/
  - custom.ini
- .env
- docker-compose.yml

docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    image: nginx:1.15.6
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    volumes:
      - ./code:/code
      - ./nginx/site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
      - ./nginx/logs:/var/log/nginx
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - php
  php:
    build: ./phpfpm
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./phpfpm/custom.ini:/opt/bitnami/php/etc/conf.d/custom.ini
      - ./code:/code
  db:
    image: postgres:10.1
    volumes:
      - ./postgres/data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_DB=${DB_NAME}
      - POSTGRES_USER=${DB_USER}
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=${DB_PASSWORD}
    ports:
      - 5400:5432
```

There are some questions :

- Why docker doesn't exist in Linux services? but when I install docker by apt-get it goes to Linux services list. How can I set docker as a service and enable it for  loading on startup?
- How can I set docker-compose in Linux services to run when system startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install docker with package `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/package.deb` that you can download from https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/dists/.

Then do post install, `sudo systemctl enable docker`. This will start docker at system boots, combined with `restart: always` your previous compose will be restarted automatically.

Answer (score 0):

1. I think that dockerd is creating a daemon, but you have to enable it.

   $ sudo systemctl enable docker
2. Add `restart: always` to your db container.
   [How the docker restart policies work](https://serverfault.com/questions/884759/how-does-restart-always-policy-work-in-docker-compose)

Comment: thanks for your answer but when i install docker form binaries there isn't any services of docker . the only way to start docker daemon is "dockerd" command. about number 2 I want to start "docker-compose up " when linux started up